Definition of Cayley transform
I have a very stupid question. I saw in different sources different definition of Cayley Transform. My question is: Can the functions $\phi_c : \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{H}, \, \phi_c(z) = i \frac{1-z}{1+z}$ and $\psi_c : \mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{D}, \, \psi_c(z) = \frac{i-z}{i+z}$? be named Cayley transforms, or is a standard notation? Thanks!

One should be the Cayley transformation,  the other its inverse.

This is certainly one of the most famous maps.
You can check that $z\to \frac{i-z}{i+z}$ maps $-1,0,1$ to $-i,1,i,$ respectively. Thus the real line goes onto the unit circle (as this is a Möbius transformation).
Then check that $i\to 0$ to see that the upper half plane goes to the unit disk.

Feed this one into $z\to i\frac {1-z}{1+z}$ to get $$i\frac {1-\frac {i-z}{i+z}}{1+\frac {i-z}{i+z}}=i\frac {\frac {2z}{i+z}}{\frac {2i}{i+z}}=i\frac zi=z,$$ to see that they are inverses.
